# Transistor is OFF but the voltage at the emitter is the same as voltage at the collector

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, npn, pnp

This is simple simulation below of an NPN transistor:

[image]

In the above transistor, without giving any base voltage, whatever voltage I give at the collector of the transistor, I am getting at the emitter. The voltage drop across the resistor is ZERO.

From my understanding, the transistor is turned OFF when there is no base-emitter voltage. From the above simulation, the base and emitter terminals of the transistor are floating. But still the voltage appears at the bottom end of the resistor. How is this possible? What is happening inside the N-P-N regions of the transistor for this behaviour to happen?

If I connect the resistor to ground, there is a very small current of 10pA, flowing through the resistor. How is this possible and how can any current flow, when the transistor is supposed to be OFF? (There is no defined base-emitter voltage applied.)

Can someone please explain?

Comment: You get the same voltage because **no current is flowing**. For a voltage drop to occur, there needs to be a voltage source present (there isn't) or there needs to be a **current** flowing through a **resistor** resulting in a voltage drop. Your emitter and base are floating so no current can flow so no voltage is dropped. Add a 10 Mohm resistor from emitter to Ground and simulate again.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. My doubt was that, since the transistor has 3 regions internally, N-P-N, won't that block the voltage from the collector to the emitter?

Comment: You're probably comparing this situation to a **open switch** where indeed, you would measure (simulate) a voltage of 0 V. But an opened switch is a "real open", there is no connection. A transistor that is off is not the same, there is always some high resistance connection still present (the leakage of the transistor junctions).

Comment: And, I have a voltage source +5V connected to the collector of the transistor.

Comment: *N-P-N, won't that block the voltage from the collector to the emitter?* Yes but **not enough**. In your situation the transistor that is off has a **very high resistance** but the connection between the emitter and ground has an **infinite** resistance. So the infinite resistance "wins" and all the voltage will drop across it.

Comment: Do this again on a bench using a real transistor and a multimeter and then the transistor will "win" (5 V across transistor, almost 0 V measured on multimeter) because the resistance of a transistor that is off is **higher** than the 10 Mohm input resistance of your multimeter.

Comment: Yes. I measured this voltage in a similar type of circuit. And that's why I came back to the simulation to verify it. And both results are the same. Just couldn't understand the theory behind it and want to understand what point I am missing and which concept I am misunderstanding over here?

Comment: Yes, you forgot about the fact that a transistor isn't an ideal switch. Even when off, it leaks a small amount of current (that 10 pA you have seen).

Comment: It also is a simulation.  10pA is the matehematical equivalent of 0, when you compare it to mA.  If transistor is off, emitter should be pulled to ground.  No simulation is perfect.

Comment: Connect the other end of the resistor to 0V. Now measure the voltage from C to E.